# Acceder con PHP a un objeto dentro de muchos otros sin recorrerlos todos

Tags: php

Tengo el siguiente objeto:

```
   $statsObject = {
    "quiz_statistics": [
    {
        "id": "10",
        "question_statistics": [
            {
                "id": "8",
                "estatistics": {
                    "property1": 1,
                    "property2": 2
                }
            }
        ]
    }
    ]
}
```

Y hasta ahora para llegar hasta el objeto 'estatistics' tenía que recorrerlos todos con una función como está:

```
foreach ($statsObject[0] as $nombre => $valor) {
        foreach ($valor as $estado => $dato) {
            foreach ($dato as $other => $search) {
                if ($other == 'statistics') {
                    foreach ($search as $final => $result) {

                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Hay forma de llegar hasta 'statistics' y empezar ahí a recorrer sus elementos sin tener que hacer tanto foreach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

podes ir testeando [si es array](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.is-array.php), [si es object](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.is-object.php), [si el object tiene una propiedad](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.property-exists.php) y [tomando el primer elemento del array](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.reset.php) cuando corresponda. Como alternativa fijate si podes aplanarlo a un array y acceder via keys.

```php
<?php
$statsObject = json_decode('
{
    "quiz_statistics": [
    {
        "id": "10",
        "question_statistics": [
            {
                "id": "8",
                "estatistics": {
                    "property1": 1,
                    "property2": 2
                }
            }
        ]
    }
    ]
}', false);
print_r ( $statsObject ); echo PHP_EOL;
print_r ( is_object( $statsObject ) ); echo PHP_EOL;
print_r ( property_exists( 'statsObject', 'quiz_statistics' ) ); echo PHP_EOL;
print_r ( is_array( $statsObject->quiz_statistics ) ); echo PHP_EOL;
$elArray = $statsObject->quiz_statistics;
print_r ( !empty( $elArray ) ); echo PHP_EOL;
$firstof = reset( $elArray );
print_r ( is_object( $firstof ) ); echo PHP_EOL;
print_r ( property_exists( $firstof, 'question_statistics' ) ); echo PHP_EOL;
print_r ( is_array( $firstof->question_statistics ) ); echo PHP_EOL;

$elArrayQuestion = $firstof->question_statistics;
print_r ( !empty( $elArrayQuestion ) ); echo PHP_EOL;
$firstofQuestion = reset( $elArrayQuestion );

print_r ( property_exists( $firstofQuestion, 'estatistics' ) ); echo PHP_EOL;
print_r ( is_array( $firstofQuestion->estatistics ) ); echo PHP_EOL;
print_r ( is_object( $firstofQuestion->estatistics ) ); echo PHP_EOL;

$estatistics = $firstofQuestion->estatistics;
print_r ( $estatistics ); echo PHP_EOL;

print_r ( '---- objetos, arrays, reset' ); echo PHP_EOL;

print_r ( reset( reset( $statsObject->quiz_statistics )->question_statistics )->estatistics ); echo PHP_EOL;


$statsObject2 = json_decode('
{
    "quiz_statistics": [
    {
        "id": "10",
        "question_statistics": [
            {
                "id": "8",
                "estatistics": {
                    "property1": 1,
                    "property2": 2
                }
            }
        ]
    }
    ]
}', true);
print_r ( '----como array ---' ); echo PHP_EOL;
print_r ( $statsObject2 ); echo PHP_EOL;
print_r ( $statsObject2['quiz_statistics'][0]['question_statistics'][0]['estatistics'] ); echo PHP_EOL;
```

---

`resultado`

```
stdClass Object
(
    [quiz_statistics] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [id] => 10
                    [question_statistics] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => stdClass Object
                                (
                                    [id] => 8
                                    [estatistics] => stdClass Object
                                        (
                                            [property1] => 1
                                            [property2] => 2
                                        )

                                )

                        )

                )

        )

)

1

1
1
1
1
1
1
1

1
stdClass Object
(
    [property1] => 1
    [property2] => 2
)

---- objetos, arrays, reset
stdClass Object
(
    [property1] => 1
    [property2] => 2
)

----como array ---
Array
(
    [quiz_statistics] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 10
                    [question_statistics] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [id] => 8
                                    [estatistics] => Array
                                        (
                                            [property1] => 1
                                            [property2] => 2
                                        )

                                )

                        )

                )

        )

)

Array
(
    [property1] => 1
    [property2] => 2
)
```

Comment: Perfecto, justo lo que necesitaba. Gracias.