# ¿Está sería la manera correcta de acceder a los elementos de un array multidimensional?

Tags: php

Obtengo los datos de una API, la URL es la siguiente https://api.bridgedataoutput.com/api/v2/OData/test/Property?access_token=6baca547742c6f96a6ff71b138424f21

Mi controlador:

```
public function index()
{
    $data = file_get_contents("https://api.bridgedataoutput.com/api/v2/OData/test/Property?access_token=6baca547742c6f96a6ff71b138424f21");

    $properties = json_decode($data, true);

    return view('welcome', compact('properties'));
}
```

En la vista objento en el primer foreach los elemntos del primer nivel del array, y con el segundo nivel obtengo los que selecciono directamente, tales cómo `FireplaceFeatures`, `View`:

```
@foreach ($properties['value'] as $key => $value)

    {{  $value['ListPrice'] }} <br>

    @foreach ($value['FireplaceFeatures'] as $key => $FireplaceFeatures)

        {{  $FireplaceFeatures }} <br>

    @endforeach

    @foreach ($value['View'] as $key => $view)

        {{  $view }} <br>

    @endforeach

@endforeach
```

Es la manera correcta como obtengo los datos de los elementos del segundo nivel?

Comment: faltarían un par de checks por si las claves no coinciden o no existen

Comment: Perfecto, podrían ser condicionales IF?

Comment: por lo general si, hay varias funciones para testear por ej: https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/367219/81450 , según como venga la app podes meterle un filtro o función que sanitize y/o ponga defaults antes de enviar al view

Comment: Gracias nuevamente, ya reviso el enlace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu opción es correcta. Como dicen en los comentarios, podrías chequear si las claves existen con la función array_key_exists().

Otra opción podría ser usar la función **array_column()** de php que devuelve los valores de una sola columna del array.

```
$listPrice = array_column($properties['value'], "ListPrice");

$fireplaceFeatures = array_column($properties['value'], "FireplaceFeatures");

$view = array_column($properties['value'], "View");
```

Luego dependiendo como quieras mostrar los datos podrías hacer algo así:

```
foreach($listPrice as $key => $lp) {
    echo $lp . '<br/><br/>';
    
    echo implode("<br/>", $fireplaceFeatures[$key]) . '<br/><br/>';
    
    echo implode("<br/>", $view[$key]) . '<br/><br/>';
}
```

La salida sería (la corto en la tercer iteración):

```
761167

One
Living Room Fireplace
Wood
Gas

View
Lake View

485425

One
Living Room Fireplace
Wood
Gas



105162

One
Living Room Fireplace
Wood

View
Lake View
....
```

Comment: Muchas gracias!

Comment: De nada @Joseph!